# Short story about a woman betrothed to an Orc and delayed wedding by re-decorating castle. Title had swatch in it.

Tags: story-identification

Does anyone know of a short Scifi story in a compilation book - woman sent to marry an Orc - *swatch* was in the title. She agreed to marry if she could redesign and decorate the whole of the Orcs castle.....  Thanks.

Comment: Hi welcome to Sci-Fi.SE... Could you please add some more details about the book (i.e. dates etc.).

Comment: @mooz - Well, giving the title is certainly a big help; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi

Answer (score 6):

You're referring to "[Death Swatch](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=25QeAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT54&lpg=PT54&dq=death%20swatch%20friesner&source=bl&ots=xgS1sQkHXd&sig=VSd7VxRYK7jxKhebEujv3hw58ts&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XP8EVPDbEujm7AaM64BY&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=death%20swatch%20friesner&f=false)" by Esther Friesner

> "I am backing out of nothing, my lord," the princess returned
>   smoothly. "But by those same bonds of magic, whose power not even you
>   dare to challenge, I call to mind the fact that we cannot be wed until
>   you have satisfied the one condition of a royal elfmaid's marriage."
>
> "I had the blood test," the Grim Lord snarled.
>
> "Not that. I mean... the Gift!"

then her brainwave

> "I want to redecorate."
>
> "What?"
>
> Acting as if she had just heard the most eloquent of blessings (as
>   opposed to the monosyllable of blankest confusion) Minuriel flung her
>   arms around the Grim Lord's neck and exclaimed, "Oh, thank you,
>   darling! You won't regret this. And it'll be no trouble to you,
>   absolutely no trouble at all. All I need from you is your cooperation;
>   I'll handle everything else. Just wait, you'll be so pleased with the
>   results, you won't know what to think!"

It was collected in "[The Mammoth Book of Comic Fantasy](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1037577.The_Mammoth_Book_of_Comic_Fantasy)".